# The tetrahedron is a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology

I have been thinking that simplicial complexes can not be given topological manifold structure since a simplicial complex is a union of simplices of different dimensions, hence there may be are points with neighborhoods homeomorphic to different dimensional euclidian spaces. Then I've been told that the  tetrahedron which is a simplicial complex is also a $2$-dimensional topological manifold. what about vertices of the tetrahedron and the points on the edges, do they have neighborhoods homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: They do, the tetrahedron itself is homeomorphic to the 2-sphere $S^2$. Try to convince yourself of that. On the other hand, the tetrahedron is not *diffeo*-morphic to the sphere, and it's not a smooth manifold -- you can only get a continuous equivalence. Maybe that's what is confusing you?

Comment: The $2$-sphere has a one-dimensional equator and two zero-dimensional poles. That doesn't stop it from being a manifold.

Comment: Yes but on the sphere the points seem 'at least geometrically' to be equivalent and the neighborhood you choose for one point, you can choose a similar neighborhood for another point, but on the tetrahedron the vertex points and the points on the edges seem to be different from other points lying inside the triangles of the tetrahedron.

Comment: A triangle is homeomorphic to a 120 degree sector of a disk. Glue three of those together, and you have a full disk.

Comment: I would consider it as a generalization to manifold with boundaries. There are even manifolds with corners...I guess the strict sense manifold definition is only for starters.

Comment: The sphere has no boundary so the tetrahedron homeomorphic to the sphere can't be topological manifold with boundary

Comment: @palio: are you speaking of the boundary of the tetrahedron? Usually (for instance in simplicial homology), a tetrahedron of dimension $n$ is the convex hull of $n+1$ affinely independant points, hence is homeomorphic to a closed ball. Maybe this is what confuses Troy Woo.

Answer (score 0):

The usual hierarchy of manifolds 'with structure' is that smooth manifolds and piecewise linear manifolds are contained in the class of piecewise differentiable manifolds (although there is an equivalence between piecewise linear and piecewise differentiable because of Whitead's triangulation theorem) which are contained in the class of topological manifolds. There are a few other kinds of manifolds which fit somewhere into this hierarchy, but these are the main ones. Piecewise linear manifolds are probably exactly what you think they are, they are roughly the manifolds you can construct by gluing together disks such that they overlap in a piecewise linear way. They can be defined in terms of an atlas whose transition functions are all piecewise linear.

You should hopefully be able to see that the tetrahedron is a manifold whose faces can be glued together in such a way that the open 'flaps' on the faces overlap in a piecewise linear way, and so the tetrahedron is a PL manifold. As the class of PL manifolds is contained in the class of topological manifolds, this means that the tetrahedron is also a topological manifold, and in fact this is easiest to see by noting that the tetrahedron is homeomorphic to a sphere, and so in particular every point in the tetrahedron has a neighbourhood which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ - the definition of a topological manifold.